# Why is it that any two distinct subgroups of G of order p (prime) intersect in 1?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Why is it that any two distinct subgroups of G of order p (prime) intersect in 1?

It says so [here on page 29](http://books.google.dk/books?id=pYk6AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA29).

But why is it?

Comment: Their intersection has to be a subgroup of each of them. What are the only subgroups of a group of prime order?

Comment: so because the order of $S\cap P$ for $P, S \in Syl_pG$ and $S\neq P$ divides the order of $S$ and the order of $P$ it must be either 1 or $p$ but it can't be $p$ because $P$ and $S$ are distinct?

Comment: Exactly. So their intersection must be trivial.

Comment: great. thanks a lot!

Comment: @lhf: Done. $\quad$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer to get the question off the Unanswered list:

HINT: If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and of $K$. What are the only subgroups of a group of prime order?